# How to separate frontend and admin in CodeIgniter framework?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I started working on a project which should have admin panel and frontend and I want to use CodeIgniter framework on client request. But the problem is I am not able to understand how to start the project as mentioned above.
I want folder similar to the image shared

[image]

Comment: You mean only authenticated user can access "admin" zone? If it is correct, you should have a `Admin_controller` in `application/core`. Constructor of this controller checks permission of current user and allows / denies access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the Admin_controller (for separeted security rules), for better organization, it's good to use some extension like this one:

HMVC: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/src

With this you'll be able to that this type os structure:

[image]

URLs

```
http://awesome.site/public_controller

http://awesome.site/*module_name*/*controller_inside_module*

http://awesome.site/admin/login
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Codeigniter's session functionality to authenticate the user and his role (e.g., "admin", "customer", etc)

Then add a constructor like this to every controller (this is just an example)

```
class Admin_only extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if( !isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in']) || $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['user_type'] != 'administrator' )
        {
            // you're not welcome here
            redirect('welcome/access_error');
        }

    }
```

The __construct() is run every time anything within the controller is accessed.

See how in my example (there's cleaner ways, but this will definitely work), I'm constantly checking if the user is logged in AND if the user is an administrator (actually I'm checking the opposite... logged out OR not administrator, but it's pretty much the same thing logically) and if the check fails, the user is redirected away from the controller.